# How to hide products from shop page if ACF field on product edit page is checked - WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

i want to hide products only from Shop Page (on category page, this products should be shown). For this i am using ACF checkbox field. I want to hide all products from Shop Page if this products have checkbox checked.

```
function remove() {
  global $product;
  $rem = get_field('remove');
  if(is_shop() ) :
   
  endif; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you spent more than 1 min in google you could find atleast 100 results with examples.
Put the following function in your active theme functions.php
Here is a solution:

```
//Checkbox returns 0 or 1 so exclude should be 1 in your case
function exclude_products_from_shop( $q ) {
if(!is_shop()) return;
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'remove',
        'value'     => '0',
        'compare'   => '=',
    );
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'exclude_products_from_shop' );
```